# Passar os dados de um spinner para o mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql

Ola, então a minha duvida e pequena e simples (mas que eu não consigo resolver kkk) apenas quero saber como passar o valor que foi selecionado no Spinner para o banco de dados ao clicar em um botão, aqui o meu script

```
   sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int posicao, long id) {
            nome = parent.getItemAtPosition(posicao).toString();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
    btadcionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                String aluno = adicionarnome.getText().toString();
                String patrulha = nome;

            if (aluno.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nenhum campo pode esta vaio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                url = "http://smestudios.000webhostapp.com/adadmirin/registre.php";

                parametros = "aluno=" + aluno + "patrulha=" + patrulha;

                new SolicitaDados().execute(url);
            }
        }
    });
}
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class SolicitaDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], parametros);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nenhum campo pode esta vazio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        adicionarnome.setText(resultado);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho melhor pegar o objeto e depois fazer o cast

`Object objeto = parent.getItemAtPosition(posicao);`

`String nome = ((String) objeto).getNome();`

Aqui voce já possui o nome, agora basta utilizar sua classe `new SolicitaDados()` e realizar o commit no banco, não sei O conteudo de SolicitarDados().

Edite sua pergunta e mostre o conteúdo desta classe para podermos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado mano, c meu quebrou um galho